# Como agrupar subtração de campos iguais no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query

Preciso fazer uma consulta que retorne o saldo atual do funcionário.
Sendo que na minha modelagem eu separo os débitos e créditos do funcionário pelos campos tipo `1` para créditos e `2` para débitos. A minha consulta não está trazendo o valor total agrupado por funcionário, ela retorna apenas a subtração do primeiro registro encontrado.

```
SELECT 
 (SELECT SUM(valor) from `conta_corrente_funcionario` c WHERE `tipo` = '1') -
 (SELECT SUM(valor) from `conta_corrente_funcionario` d WHERE `tipo` = '2') as total

FROM conta_corrente_funcionario` totais
    group by
    totais.idFuncionario
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função `IF` pode ser útil, pois você resolve com apenas uma *query*:

```
SELECT
   SUM( IF( tipo='1', valor, -valor ) ) AS total
FROM
   conta_corrente_funcionario
GROUP BY
   idFuncionario
```

Desta forma, de acordo com o `tipo` o valor será somado com sinal invertido, ou seja, o mesmo que subtraído (pode ser necessário trocar o "-" de lado no caso real, depende se está usando terminologia popular ou contábil para o que é débito e o que é crédito).

Se quiser obter os valores em colunas separadas:

```
SELECT
   SUM( IF( tipo='1', valor, 0 ) ) AS creditos,
   SUM( IF( tipo='2', valor, 0 ) ) AS debitos
FROM
   conta_corrente_funcionario
GROUP BY
   idFuncionario
```

Neste caso estamos dizendo que *"para cada linha, se o tipo for 1, soma-se o `valor` nos créditos. Senão, some `0`"*. O mesmo raciocínio se aplica para os débitos.

A sintaxe da função `IF` é

```
IF( condição de teste, valor retornado se verdadeiro, valor retornado se falso )
```

Comment: Perfeito Bacco, entendi como usar a sintaxe da função `IF`  e atendeu perfeitamente a minha necessidade.